# Perlbrew keeps forgetting my default Perl when I close my terminal

Tags: bash, perl, perlbrew

I have installed perlbrew on a Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa system. When I type `perlbrew list` it shows:

```
  perl-5.16.0
  perl-5.22.0
```

If I type `perlbrew switch perl-5.22.0` it says:

```
A sub-shell is launched with perl-5.22.0 as the activated perl. Run 'exit' to finish it.
```

When I check this with `perlbrew list`it shows the correct output:

```
 perl-5.16.0

* perl-5.22.0
```

But as soon as I close my terminal it forgets that `perl-5.22.0` was set to be my default Perl.